# Using Sequence in FOR LOOP to insert rows in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I had problem in using Sequence in For Loop to insert rows in Oracle table, after going through some blog if found the correct usage.

**Wrong usage:** -- Inserted only one row, since it is not incremented

```
DECLARE ASSET_CLAIM_STAGE_ID NUMBER := tblAssetClaimStage_ID_SEQ.NextVal;

    BEGIN

      FOR SI IN 1..STAGEID LOOP
        INSERT INTO tblAssetClaimStage (assetClaimStageID, assetID, claimstageID, createDateTime)
                SELECT ASSET_CLAIM_STAGE_ID, IN_ASSETID, SI, IN_SOLDDATE FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ASSETID 
                 FROM tblAssetClaimStage
                WHERE assetID = IN_ASSETID AND
                claimstageID = SI);          
      END LOOP;
```

**Correct usage:**

```
FOR SI IN 1..STAGEID LOOP
        INSERT INTO tblAssetClaimStage (assetClaimStageID, assetID, claimstageID, createDateTime)
                SELECT tblAssetClaimStage_ID_SEQ.NextVal, IN_ASSETID, SI, IN_SOLDDATE FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ASSETID 
                 FROM tblAssetClaimStage
                WHERE assetID = IN_ASSETID AND
                claimstageID = SI);          
END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
```

Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think a sequence should be incremented if not in a loop?  12c provides auto-increment.  What version of Oracle is this?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0, I want to increment the SEQ inside the LOOP

Comment: Simple answer: no. What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the loop using `forall`. However if you really have to loop, your example looks fine.